# Access Windows 10 offline maps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, bing-maps

Is there a way to access Windows 10 offline maps?

I don't mean by getting a Bing maps token etc. I mean, is there an api for them for a Windows Store app or .net app?

EDIT

I want to use the map data in my app. Not to launch the Windows 10 Maps app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three options to using the offline maps;

1. Use the Maps app that is in Windows 10.
2. Launch the Maps app in Windows 10 from your app using protocol
   activation:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app I believe this is what you are after.
3. Use the map control that is built into the Windows 10 SDK. This
   requires a Bing Maps key/token.

Comment: Just to confirm I understood you correctly, the answer is _No. there is no way for my .net or UWP app to use the map data without a Bing Maps token._ Right?

Comment: Correct. You can't access the map data directly unless you use the built in API's which require a Bing Maps token.

Comment: @rbrundritt I downloaded UK maps offline but how can I use them in my app using `MapControl` ? I don't want to open default maps app using Launcher APIs.

Comment: If the maps are offline, the MapControl will automatically us the offline data unless you have an internet connection, then it will do geocoding and routing online as that is more accurate, but the map itself will still use offline data.